# 413 request entity too large apache "tomcat"

Tags: apache, tomcat8, business-intelligence, business-objects

User when access BOBJ tomcat URL the AD SSO works without any issues, when the user tries to access the Apache load balancer, then we get the Request entity too large error message.
This is happening for few of the users and few of them can login without any issues.

Setup: configured Apache Load Balancer - to connect to two tomcat server via Workers.properties.

BOBJ AD SSO is configured on Tomcat server

Error :Request Entity Too Large
The requested resource
/BOE/portal/1712062105/BIPCoreWeb/VintelaServlet
 does not allow request data with POST requests, or the amount of data provided in the request exceeds the capacity limit.

Configuration on

Apache
Httpd:
LimitRequestLine 65536
LimitRequestBody 0
LimitRequestFieldSize 65536
LimitRequestFields 10000
ProxyIOBufferSize 65536
worker: worker.ajp13.max_packet_size=65536

Tomcat:

Request someone to help in troubleshooting the error.

Answer (score 4):

Possible solution!

Apache tomcat:

```
1.  modify /opt/ tomcat/config/server.xml 
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
                   connectionTimeout="20000"
                   redirectPort="8443"
                   maxPostSize="209715200" 
                   disableUploadTimeout="true" 
                   maxHttpHeaderSize="1006384" />

2.  modify  /tomcat/webapps/manager/WEBINFO/web.xml

       <multipart-config>
      <!-- 50MB max -->
      <max-file-size>104857600</max-file-size>
      <max-request-size>209715200</max-request-size>
      <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>
    </multipart-config>
```

Nginx:

```
1.  modify /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
2.  add this  " client_max_body_size 200M; " 

http{
client_max_body_size 200M; 
}

*  Restart tomcat server
  sudo systemctl restart tomcat
*  Restart nginx server
  sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar issue for me, but the fix was slightly different:

```
worker.ajp13.max_packet_size=65536
```

This was actually in: path/apache2/conf/extra/workers.properties  (probably just a typo in earlier answer)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain this will resolve your issue, but it seems to be related.  In Tomcat's server.xml, add the following to Connector: `maxHttpHeaderSize="65536"`.  The whole line should look something like:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" 
redirectPort="8443" compression="on" URIEncoding="UTF-8" compressionMinSize="2048" 
noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata" 
compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript,text/json,application/json" 
maxHttpHeaderSize="65536" />
```

Comment: Yes, we have maxHttpheaderSize="65536" for tomcat and packet size="65536" set for ajp in server.xml

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is with the Apache parameter under Worker.properties file

We initial have set this to -> worker.ajp13.max_packet_size="65536"

However the syntax should be this :
worker..max_packet_size="65536”

**Your site** is basically the tomcat site which we refereed as worker1 and worker2.
Once we changed that value to below

worker: worker1.max_packet_size="65536"

This issue got fixed.

Hope this helps for users who have configure Apache as load balancer to two or more tomcat web application clusters.